# Exit state at end of line in ace editor syntax highlighter

Tags: syntax-highlighting, ace-editor, lexical-analysis

I'm writing a syntax highlighter for Ace Editor, and I'm having trouble correctly lexing function calls in this language. Function calls have two basic forms:

With parentheses:

```
function(foo, "bar")
```

With colons:

```
function: foo, "bar"
```

I can detect both forms, but once I go into the state of a colon-style function call, I have trouble getting back *out* of that state (which messes up the following lines). In particular, this problem exists when the function call ends with a string.

Below I've made a smaller version of the highlighter, that only focuses on this problem. The structure might seem overly complex, but bear in mind that this is part of a larger lexer, which I think warrants the complexity.

You can try it out in the [mode creator](http://ace.c9.io/tool/mode_creator.html) with the following snippet, in which the third line does not get properly highlighted.

```
function(a, "bar")
function: a, "bar"
function("bar", a)
function: "bar", a
function("bar")
```

And here's the syntax definition:

```js
define(function(require, exports, module) {
"use strict";

var oop = require("../lib/oop");
var TextHighlightRules = require("./text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;

var MyHighlightRules = function() {

    var functions = [ "function" ];

    this.$rules = {
        "start" : [
            {
                token : 'keyword',
                regex : '\\b(?:' + functions.join('|') + ')(?=\\s*[:(])',
                push  : [
                    { include : 'function' },
                ]
            }
        ],
        // A function call
        'function' : [
            {
                token : 'text',
                regex : /(?:[:(])/,
                push  : [
                    { include : 'comma_list' },
                ]
            }, {
                token : 'keyword',
                regex : /(?:\)|(?=$))/,
                next  : 'pop'
            }
        ],
        // A series of arguments, separated by commas
        'comma_list' : [
            {
                token : 'text',
                regex : /\s+/,
            }, {
                token : 'string',
                regex : /"/,
                next : 'string',
            }, {
                include : "variable_name"
            }
        ],
        'variable-name' : [
            {
                token : 'keyword',
                regex : /[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*/,
                // This makes no difference
                next : 'pop'
            },
        ],
        'string': [
            {
                token : 'string.quoted',
                regex : /"/,
                next  : 'pop'
            },
            { defaultToken : 'string.quoted' }
        ],
    };

    this.normalizeRules();
};

oop.inherits(MyHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

exports.MyHighlightRules = MyHighlightRules;
});
```

In specific: the `/(?:\)|(?=$))/` in `function` seems to match only if the previous state was **not** a string. How can I get it to match regardless, so my lexer exists the function call even with colon-style function calls?

To confound things even more, if I change the regex to `/(?:|(?=$))/` it highlights all the lines correctly, even though I can't understand why. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that at the end of line ace allows only one state transition https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/tokenizer.js#L317. So after matching `"` at the end of line and switching to function state, it won't call regexp again so `$` won't match anything. You probably can report this issue on github.

second issue is variable_name variable-name typo in your code.

Here's a modified version of your highlighter, which uses `^` in addition to `$` to get highlighting similar to what you wanted.

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
"use strict";

var oop = require("../lib/oop");
var TextHighlightRules = require("./text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;

var MyHighlightRules = function() {

    var functions = [ "function" ];

    this.$rules = {
        "start" : [
            {
                token : 'keyword',
                regex : '\\b(?:' + functions.join('|') + ')(?=\\s*[:(])',
                push  : [
                    { include : 'function' },
                ]
            }
        ],
        // A function call
        'function' : [
            {
                token : 'paren',
                regex : /(?:[:(])/,
            },
            {
                token : 'paren',
                regex : /(?:\)|$|^)/,
                next  : 'pop'
            },
            { include : 'commaList' },
        ],
        // A series of arguments, separated by commas
        'commaList' : [
            {
                token : 'text',
                regex : /\s+/,
            }, {
                token : 'string.start',
                regex : /"/,
                push : 'string',
            }, {
                include : "variableName"
            }
        ],
        'variableName' : [
            {
                token : 'variable.parameter',
                regex : /[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*/
            },
        ],
        'string': [
            {
                token : 'string.end',
                regex : /"/,
                next  : 'pop'
            },
            { defaultToken : 'string.quoted' }
        ],
    };

    this.normalizeRules();
};

oop.inherits(MyHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

exports.MyHighlightRules = MyHighlightRules;
});
```